# Check the Availability of the cube using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssas

Suppose we have 10 Cubes in Server X,
How do we Check the availability of all those cubes in powershell.

Basically, My approach was to trigger one dummy query if it is successfully executed against a cube then it is successful else not.

Help me achieve it.

Comment: A good place to start is with the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/powershell-scripting-in-analysis-services).

Comment: Probably this approach is the correct one. You have to define a criteria about that cube being "available", running a query against it suits the purpose, however try making a query that'll not consume too much resources. (Should a cube be a database, a `use db; select 1;` would be a decent start.)